# missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

Tags: python, discord.py

**Bot is not responding while typing *Travis* in the message. How can i solve this problem? Please Help**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg, ctx):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in msg.content:
            await msg.delete()


    if "Travis" in msg.content:
        await msg.add_reaction("<:webp:784320972400361483>")
    
    if "Travis" in msg.content:
        await ctx.send(f"Hey {ctx.author.mention}, He might be busy in real life so please DM him if you have a important work")
    

   


    await client.process_commands(msg)
```

Comment: You don't pass `ctx` in events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event `on_message` does not take `ctx` as parameter. If you want to pass `ctx` as parameter to do `ctx.send()` you can also use `message.channel.send()` for simplicity.

Look the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) for reference.

Your code corrected:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in msg.content:
            await msg.delete()

    if "Travis" in msg.content:
        await msg.add_reaction("<:webp:784320972400361483>")
    
    if "Travis" in msg.content:
        await msg.channel.send(f"Hey {msg.author.mention}, He might be busy in real life so please DM him if you have a important work")
    
    await client.process_commands(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

`on_message` doesn't take in `ctx` as an argument; you can do everything that you're trying to do with just `message`. You're code is also repetitive, since you can combine the `add_reaction` and `send` under one if-block. Try this out:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.delete()

    if "Travis" in message.content:
        await message.add_reaction("<:webp:784320972400361483>")
        await message.channel.send(f"Hey {message.author.mention}, He might be busy in real life so please DM him if you have a important work")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: It's an unknown emoji cause it's a custom one and you do not have it in your server